# Drag and Drop Multiple select boxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two multiple select boxes. I need to use JQuery to drag selected items from one combobox to the next. Is this at all possible?

I need to drag items from this box

```
     <select id="select1"  multiple=multiple> 
<option  value="1">test1</option> 
<option  value="2">test2</option> 
<option  value="3">test3</option> </select>
```

to this box

```
<select id="select2" multiple=multiple>
<option value="4">test4</option>
</select>
```

Any pointers help will be appreciated

Comment: You could do this with styled lists (or other html element), but not with `select`, since they're handled by the underlying OS/platform rather than the browser.

Comment: @David - Thank you, I'll definitely remember this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did was use the JUI sortable JQuery plugin and that worked for me as I wanted it to.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#empty-lists